# How do i make my view start under the statusbar in ios6 just like in ios7

Tags: ios, ios6, interface-builder, ios7

Not sure about the title of this question... it's a work in progress.

Anyway, while the internets are full of folks that want to make their `ios7` status bar behave the old way, i'm fine with that. However, my problem now is that the `view` that starts at y=0 in IOS7 jumps down under the status bar in `IOS6`.

I can and have solved this with the 'delta' `ios6/7` thing in interface builder, but i would rather have my views behave exactly the same way, i.e. my top 20 pixels can be seen in IOS7, but are hidden by a black bar in IOS6. This means that all objects end up in the same Y position before and after IOS7 if you see what i mean.

I've tried all sorts of stuff to no avail. Is there an easy way to tell `xcode` that i want my view to start at position 0 and disregard the `statusbar` in IOS6?

Comment: I dont believe there's a way to do this in iOS6, since status bar is not part of the application view as in iOS7. If you can, just hide the status bar to reclaim those 20px.

Comment: Yeah i see what your saying, but i want the bar to show. I just dont want my screen to "jump down" 20 pixels compared to IOS7... Oh well, guess i'll start fiddling with those deltas and autosizings.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this in all view's `viewDidLoad`

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```